# How to fix order by?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I got this code in asp.net mvc3 controller for view and order in a dropdown. But my problem is as you can see in the picture below it order by `text and next to it the number`. How to fix this issue?.

```
ViewBag.AddrBarangay = new SelectList(db.Barangays, "BarangayId", "BarangayName", "").OrderBy(m => m.Text);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please let me know, number is along with the text or it's separate column? or you are concatenate both? do u understand my point?

Comment: @Rajpurohit it is along with the text.

Comment: you mean "BarangayName" column contain "Barangay 1","Barangay 101" right?

Comment: @Rajpurohit yes that's correct

Comment: you have to separate both text and number in separate column then you can get you expected result then query will be

ViewBag.AddrBarangay = new SelectList(db.Barangays, "BarangayId", "BarangayName", "").OrderBy(m => m.Text).ThenBy(a=>a.Number);

Comment: except for that solution. Is there any solution with my problem?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, you have to create new Comparer which can sort in [lexicograhical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)
You should have your own implementation of comparer which implements `IComparer<string>` interface. Your comparer should be like this :

```
public class LexicoComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        var firstArgumentSplits = x.Split(' ');
        var secondArgumentSplits = y.Split(' ');

        if (firstArgumentSplits.Length == 2 && secondArgumentSplits.Length == 2)
        {
            int firstArgumentInt, secondArgumentInt;
            if (firstArgumentSplits[0] == secondArgumentSplits[0])
            {
                if (int.TryParse(firstArgumentSplits[1], out firstArgumentInt))
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(secondArgumentSplits[1], out secondArgumentInt))
                    {
                        return firstArgumentInt == secondArgumentInt ? 0 : firstArgumentInt > secondArgumentInt ? 1 : 0;
                    }

                }
            }
        }


        return String.Compare(x, y);
    }
}
```

Now you use above comparer in `OrderBy` :

```
ViewBag.AddrBarangay = new SelectList(db.Barangays,
      "BarangayId", "BarangayName", "").OrderBy(m => m.Text,
                                      new LexicoComparer());
```

Comment: Why it is in Descending order?

Comment: Oops!!! Sorry, though I had OrderBy in my mind but written OrderByDescending. Corrected

Comment: Got an error (Index was outside the bounds of the array.) if some of my data don't have a number or two word text. Sample `Brgy1 , Brgy2` it will work in `Brgy1 1 , Brgy1 2` Because of the line `int.TryParse(firstArgumentSplits[1]`

Comment: I've assumed that your data would be two word text. So, you need to update implementation as per your requirement inside Compare method. I've not fully tested with all scenario but now , you should have an idea to orderby in your custom format

Comment: @Coder can you please explain how this line works? ` if (int.TryParse(firstArgumentSplits[1], out firstArgumentInt))`

Comment: firstArgumentSplits is array of string which has been from split method by space charcter. if there are two words separated by space, it would get array of length two. firstArgumentSplit[1] give second word from array. int.TryParse is safest way to cast string to integer. if casting is done successfully, it will assign casted integer value into firstArgumentInt and returns true. if not, it'll return false.

Comment: I will study on how to use it. BTW thanks even it looks like long method :D and I use `> 1` for `== 2`

Comment: It's good approach to have your own comparer whenever you want to have your own way of sorting. Good to learn about IComparer and IComparable interface and their usage !!!

Answer (score 2):

Although IMHO the best way to solve this would be to store the values like `1,10,100` in *SelectList* value property and thensort it. If for some reason you can't do that then you need to provide the custom *EqualityComparer* in the `OrderBy` clause.

Also, if your text `Barangay` would always remain constant then you can do it this way as well (although not a very good approach as it's not generic):-

```
int maxSize = db.Barangays.Max(x => x.Text.Length);
ViewBag.AddrBarangay = new SelectList(db.Barangays, "BarangayId", "BarangayName", "")
                .OrderBy(m => m.Text.Replace("Barangay","").Trim().PadLeft(maxSize ,'0'));
```

Comment: what this line mean ?. `x => x.Text.Length` I know it will get the length of a text. Explain a bit.

Comment: @KiRa - In `maxSize` first we are determining what is the max length of your string like `Barangay 1` will give _10_ characters while `Barangay 100` would yeild _12_ characters so on _OrderBy_ clause first we are removing the common text `Barangay` and then padding extra `0` on the left so that all integer text becomes of equal length like `010,100,011` etc. and then `OrderBy` will give you correct result.

Comment: for what I understand (correct me if i'm wrong) it will only get the first data in all record?.

Comment: @KiRa - No No, it will return the sorted record only. You can test it.